# Convert Json files to JS files

Tags: javascript, json, babeljs, shelljs

I created a Module to import all JSON files in a certain Directory and now I want to convert them into JS files and export them in a directory. I want to do that using babel plugin or shellJS

```
recursiveReadDir(MODEL_PATH, [], function (err, fileNames) {

    if (err)
    {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++)
    {
        const internalPath = toInternalPath(handleSlashes(fileNames[i]))
        if (internalPath === null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        const appName = getFirstSegment(internalPath);

        const inAppPath = "." + internalPath.substr(appName.length);
        const { processName, shortName, isDomain, isComposite } = matchPath(inAppPath);
```

Comment: And your question/issue is...?

Comment: i need  to know the way that i use to convert json to js and export it in  adirectory